# Case statement skipping in Android App Activity

Tags: android, case

The following `case` statement is skipping:

```
switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    ButtonFeedback.vibrate(20);
    Log.d("ClientActivity", "Down");

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    ButtonFeedback.vibrate(20);
    Log.d("ClientActivity", "up");
```

The result in the log is "Down" "Up" when touching and holding down the button which should only be "Down" and only "up" when not touching the button, which is correct.

Anything missing here?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add break statments. Else the next case will be executed too.

```
switch(event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        ButtonFeedback.vibrate(20);
        Log.d("ClientActivity", "Down");
        break; // you forgot this break here
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        ButtonFeedback.vibrate(20);
        Log.d("ClientActivity", "up");
        break;
```

Answer (score 3):

YOu have missed `break` ,

call break after the case

i.e

```
 switch(event.getAction()) {

     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
       ButtonFeedback.vibrate(20);
  Log.d("ClientActivity", "Down");
    break;


         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           ButtonFeedback.vibrate(20);
  Log.d("ClientActivity", "up");
      break;
```

Comment: Why downvote..? downvoter..? You are destructing the Site by giving unreasonable downvote..Don't you have a dare to comment

Comment: I know that. Very annoying the downvote came just two seconds after your edit with the example. The downvoter did not see your edit.

Comment: @rekire may be..But the answer never be wrong in any instance right..even before edit

Comment: I agree with you. I personally just downvote spam so I cannot understand why your answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
switch(event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    ButtonFeedback.vibrate(20);
    Log.d("ClientActivity", "Down");
break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    ButtonFeedback.vibrate(20);
break;
```

By leaving out the `break;` statement, you created a fallthrough switch case, in which both of your cases get executed when ACTION_DOWN occurs.

Comment: You're right, Oh my god , case without break... need to make a trip to the coffee machine :)